# Mod Security ctl:ruleEngine=Off Whitelist Fails in Phase 1

Tags: apache-2.2, security, mod-security, whitelist

mod_security with custom rules and whitelists in separate .conf files - Apache 2.2, modsec 2.8

Whitelist rule:

```
SecRule REMOTE_ADDR "^10\.10\.10\.10" phase:1,nolog,allow,ctl:ruleEngine=Off,id:104008
```

If a request is sent to the server that includes e.g. `/?abc=../../` then modsec allows the request from 10.10.10.10 only, otherwise it denies the request in Phase 2 with a 403 as I would expect (due to our installed rules)

I have a customer who uses a remote WorPress management system (which is being represented here as 10.10.10.10) but that system sends certain **POST** requests which contain **Content-Length** headers but lack **Content-Type** headers.

Even when the request comes from 10.10.10.10 this results in:

```
--7ed45f75-H--
Message: Access denied with connection close (phase 1). Match of "rx ^0$" against "REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-Length" required. [file "/usr/local/apache/conf/modsec_rules/10_asl_rules.conf"] [line "93"] [id "392301"] [rev "7"] [msg "Atomicorp.com WAF Rules: Request Containing Content, but Missing Content-Type header"] [severity "NOTICE"] [tag "no_ar"]
Apache-Error: [file "config.c"] [line 395] [level 3] Handler for (null) returned invalid result code 9, referer: https://redacted.com
Action: Intercepted (phase 1)
```

I'm not sure if `ctl:ruleEngine=Off` simply can't be used in a phase 1 SecRule, or if this is a Mod Security 2.8 bug. I can confirm that there are no rules that subsequently turn ctl:ruleEngine back on.

Answer (score 0):

As you already answered to your question [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/628053/changing-modsecurity-logging-on-a-per-transaction-basis), you should create additional configuration file and put this line in it, it will disable `Atomicorp` rule you you were mentioning for this user/domain only (for everyone).

File :  /usr/local/apache/conf/userdata/std/2/**username**/**example.com**

```
<IfModule mod_security2.c>
  SecRuleRemoveById 392301
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT**

Disabling certain rule for specific IP/range would go like this

```
SecRule REMOTE_HOST "@ipmatch 1.2.0.0/16" \
"id:12345,phase:2,t:none,pass,nolog,noauditlog,ctl:ruleRemovebyID=392301"
```

As explained on [Atomicorp wiki](https://www.atomicorp.com/wiki/index.php/Mod_security)

Comment: I didn't answer my question [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/628053/changing-modsecurity-logging-on-a-per-transaction-basis) at all. My post here is to whitelist an **IP Address** not a rule. I do not want to disable this rule across the entire server, nor do i want to disable it for all requests against this virtual host - only for requests from this specific IP address. I'm afraid your solution doesn't answer my question.

Comment: I've updated answer; to 'whitelist' IP you need to make exemption for certain IP from given rule like in second example in answer. If you have list of IPs in some file use `@pmFromFile /etc/modsecurity/ip_whitelist_list` instead `@ipmatch 1.2.0.0/16` part; and make sure IPs you want whitelisted are present in that file

Comment: Dear Hrvoje. Firstly your suggestion shows phase 2 but IP matching belongs in phase 1 for efficiency. Secondly, I'm afraid you have not understood my question. I am whitelisting an IP from ALL rules. The most efficient way to do this is to turn off the rule engine. This is what my suggested rule does but due to an unknown reason modsec still blocks the request under certain conditions. Please re-read my original post.

Comment: Your question has so many details and I find it bit confusing to understand what the real problem is. Reading your last comment I understand your goal clearly. To disable all rules for some IP as you suggested `ctl:ruleEngine=Off` would need to do. Problem is if block is applied first; and rule disable only after. Is your `whitelist` attempt maybe within `Location` block? if it is you'll need to move it out since `Location` blocks are parsed last, in your case never since block kicked in already and no further rules are evaluated.